# Echo3 Framework

Tags: java, web-frameworks, echo3

What are the pros and cons of echo3 framework compared to other java web frameworks?

Answer (score 2):

Echo3 is still under development. Echo2 is stable (but old). The main "pro" is that you don't write javascript or html, you write Java GUI code. The main "con" is that it has not been widely adopted. I've used Echo2 5 years ago and it was a nice framework, but the development of Echo3 is slow (thought it has not stopped).

Perhaps it is worth taking a look at other similar frameworks like GWT or Vaadin.

These (Echo, GWT, Vaadin) differ from traditional frameworks (like spring mvc, struts, wicket) in the fact that you don't write HTML, css and javascript. That's why they are more suitable for highly-interactive web-applications that would resemble a desktop application. If you, for example, need to have bookmarkable URLs, want to rely on browser navigation and such browser-intrinsic things, don't go for Echo/GWT/Vaadin (although they do provide some support for these things)

Comment: Disclaimer: I'm a member of the Vaadin team. Yes, Vaadin's value proposition is very close to Echo: write only server-side Java code and the framework will handle everything else to produce an slick and professional browser-based UI for you. OTOH, GWT is different: it's a client-side technology, meaning that you write your code against the DOM tree, and it's run in the browser. With GWT not all Java techologies are available, and you need additional code to access server-side stuff (eg. database, EJBs etc). Vaadin is being developed at full speed and it has excellent community support.

Answer (score 0):

I went to the Echo3 website and found an argument that discouraged me from testing it. It seems that it is a dead project:

> the current version of Echo3 is 3.0.beta8, released August 6, 2009

Technically, I don't know...

Comment: even though we are living at internet speed, I won't call a developing software dead just because there hasn't been a release for a year. human brains are slow, we can' accomplish that much in a year.

Comment: That problem seems to have disappeared: 'Echo3: the current version of Echo3 is 3.0.rc1, released March 24, 2011'

Comment: The original maintainer has somehow disappeared. The community maintains an updated version at https://github.com/echo3/echo3 at a moderate pace.

Answer (score 0):

Recently the final 3.0.1 version has been released. A 3.1 version (with WebSocket integration etc.) is just around the corner.

The original creator/maintainer has all but dissapeared, but there are considerable community efforts in reviving the project (and make it less dependent on a single (albeit very gifted) person).

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but some people may still ask it...

I've been working with Echo3 for some time now, and the biggest problems are indeed that is is not widely adopted, as already mentioned and that the development progresses very slow.

When choosing a framework, you normally limit yourself to it's technologies, and Echo3 simply lacks a few things that I always missed in my projects. For example, the Echo3 table component offers no scrolling, no pagination and no sorting. And a table is one of the most important a components a framework can offer (Echolot has a nice table component, but it only supports text values and currently has no sorting).

So have a good look at the Echo3 showcase at http://demo.nextapp.com/echo3csjs/ and at the widget libraries at http://echo.nextapp.com/site/echo3/addons and see if that is enough for you.

Also, it changes the way you can design and layout your applications. Echo3 gives you the usual desktop components, like rows, columns, grids and panels. However, it doesn't offer layout manager concepts like Swing does and also does not have any CSS support. When having to follow exact design rules which involve exact positionings and behaviours of components you might have trouble doing this with Echo3.